# Update textfield using a selectbox in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to rails and I have a form below where I need to update a text field(car price) using the option selected in the select box (adjust price). drop down needs to have multiple percentage option like 100% , 50% and 25%. when one percentage is selected then it should update the car price in the field with new calculated adjusted price.

```
<% car =  Car.find(params[:id]) %>

<table class="part" width="100%">
  <tr style="vertical-align: top;">
    <td><b>Car Model</b></td>
    <td><b>Price</b></td>
    <td><b>Adjusted price</b></td>
 </tr>

<tr style="vertical-align: top;">
  <td><%= text_field(‘Car’, ‘car_name’, size: 10, value: check_for_car_name(car.name)) %></td>
  <td><%= text_field(‘Car’, ‘price’, size: 10, value: check_for_car_price(car.price)) %></td>
  <td><%= select(adjusted price(not sure of this part)) %></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

I am not sure about the select box that how I can update the car price on the fly ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags), you can use `options_for_select` combined with `select_tag`

```rb
<%= select_tag(:city_id, options_for_select([["25%", 1], ["50%", 2]])) %>
```

this will output

```html
<option value="1">25%</option>
<option value="2">50%</option>
```

Now, to update the price dynamically you'll probably want to use javascript in your front-end for example by adding an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to your select. Then, when selected option is for example 50% you can do calculations directly on the price field by changing it's value.

```js
document.getElementById('price').value = calculated price
```

or as the question was marked for jQuery you can use .val()

```
$("#price").val() = calculated price
```

Comment: Hi @Marelons , Thanks for the answer. For percentage calculation I need to write a separate ruby method in a helper class? or it could be done using javascript ? can you please add event listner to the select ? Thanks.

Comment: Percentage calculation should be as simple as multiplying price by .25 etc.
Event listener: get your select `select = document.getElementById('cars')` and then you can add the callback that console.logs the result. `select.addEventListener('change', (event) => {console.log(event.target.value)})` now, you can use `event.target.value` to save it to a variable, modify it and insert it as a field value.